# Angular: How to compile a template in a directive and then remove watches

Tags: performance, angularjs

I have an array of objects like this:

```
{
  text: 'Some text',
  translations: ['translation1', 'translation2'],
  direction: 'ltr'
}
```

I need to render the text and all the translation. Currently I'm looping through the array using an `ng-repeat` directive which of course creates some watches for each property bound to the `$scope`, the translations array is also rendered using an `ng-repeat`. So my `ng-view` is something like this:

```
 <div ng-repeat='result in results'>
    {{ result.text }}
    <li ng-repeat='translation in result.translations'>{{ translation }}</li>
 </div>
```

Actually, this is a simplified version of what I'm rendering. The real subarray also has objects (not strings)... So there are too many watches created that I do not need because my data never changes during the $scope lifecycle. Debugging the app using [Angular Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) shows that the performance is seriously affected by those watches.

I think if I could compile the template using a custom directive and remove the watches the app would perform much better. My question is should I do that and how to do it? Is there a better way to handle this case?

Comment: Your simplified version performs quite well. Tell us about your real problem.

Comment: It's a mobile web app built using Ionic framework. It renders a large set of objects like `{ text: '', translations: [{lang: 'en', direction: 'ltr', starred: true, text: '', author: '', title: ''}] }` in an infinte-scroll view (which means watches keep adding up). The `ng-repeat` loop renders many properties of the object thus creating too many watches per page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values that you are binding to in your template do not change, you can try a library like [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce), which performs a one-off binding.

If you'd like to accomplish this without using a 3rd-party library, you could create a directive whose `link` function parses an attribute value and sets the element text, no watches required. Something like this:

```
module.directive('once', function ($parse) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            var deregister = attrs.$observe('once', function (once) {
                if (once === undefined) { return; }
                el.html($parse(once)(scope));
                deregister();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Then you'd use it like so:

```
<span once="model.property"></span>
```

The html content of the span would be set to whatever `model.property` evaluates to on your current scope.